# Enum or array with structs inside

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, enums

I have (constant) data like this:

```
(index)  Width  Height  Scale  Name
     0    640      360      1   "SD"
     1   1080      720      2   "HD"
     2   1920     1080      3  "FHD"
```

So far - I have created structure like this:

```
struct Resolution
{
    int Width;
    int Height;
    int Scale;
    std::string Name;
};
```

Now I need an object that will let me to do something like this:

```
int index = 0;
int width = Resolutions[index].Width; // 360
```

I need enum or some array that will be constant, and accessible without initialization (static?).

Comment: I don't understand, where do you need enum?

Comment: Well... I want to increment index. Im not sure if I need enum. It could be some array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start as it is constant data I would not use `std::string`.

But I would do the following:

```
struct Resolution
{
    int Width;
    int Height;
    int Scale;
    const char * Name;
};


struct Resolution Resolutions[] = {

      {640, 360, 1, "SD"},
      { 1080, 720, 2, "HD"},
      { 1920, 1080, 3, "FHD"}
    };
```

but on another note I would use lowercase variation for the variable.

Comment: Why not `std::string`?

Comment: Why put it on the heap when it is constant? It can be in the read area of the program or library

Comment: @EdHeal why not make it `const` or better yet `constexpr`?

Comment: @EdHeal `std::string` is not required to put its content on the heap, as I mentioned. Many implementations actually use the stack for small strings. Even more so as the data is constant.

Comment: @zenith it is probably no biggie, but you can't make it `constexpr` with `std::string`

Comment: Guys, can I just add "const" keyword before `struct Resolution Resolutions[] = {`?

Comment: Yes- Why not just try it?

Comment: I just did it, it works but... Just wanted to ask about any negative effects. I'm learning C++...

Comment: @Kamil The compiler will usually emit an error if you have misused `const`, so just use it wherever you can and wherever it makes sense. _Not_ using `const` has more negative effects than using it.

Comment: My point of view is to tell the compiler as much as possible. e.g. if the item/method is const.

Comment: You can also omit the `struct` keyword when defining the array.

Comment: Your right - slightly an old f*rt as been a programmer too long for these novel ideas!!!

Comment: @zenith no implementation uses the stack for strings at file scope

Comment: Whether to use `const char *` or `std::string` here may depend on what your most common usage will be; for example if you only ever will pass the string to a function expecting `const std::string &` then you waste time constructing temporaries every such call if you use `const char *`.

Answer (score 2):

You need either `std::vector` if the elements in `Resolutions` are not compile-time-constant, or `std::array` if they are and the collection doesn't need to grow. For example:

```
#include <array>
…

const std::array<Resolution, 3> Resolutions =
{{ /* Width  Height  Scale  Name */
    {  640,     360,     1,  "SD" },
    { 1080,     720,     2,  "HD" },
    { 1920,    1080,     3, "FHD" }
}};
```

---

If you want the indices to have meaningful names instead of `0`, `1`, `2`, you can make an `enum`:

```
enum ResolutionIndex { SD, HD, FHD };
```

And use it as the array index:

```
ResolutionIndex index = SD;
int width = Resolutions[index].Width;
```

This makes the code safer as you can't now do:

```
ResolutionIndex index = 4;
```

which would be an invalid index. The valid index values are hard-coded in the enum and the compiler enforces that. If you used `int`:

```
int index = 4;
```

then the compiler can't help you if you give an invalid index.

Comment: Or, if you are not using C++11 (or just do not want to use `std::array`): `const Resolution Resolutions[3] = {...};`

Comment: Why put this on the heap (with all the construction etc) when it is constant?

Comment: @ChrisDrew No you don't.

Comment: @EdHeal `std::array` is allocates on the stack.

Comment: I have "too many initializers" error too (MS Visual C++ 2013).

Comment: @ChrisDrew Actually you do need extra `{}`. Damn uniform initialization.

Comment: I read the vector version of this answer. BTW std:::string is on the heap

Comment: @EdHeal Not if it's small string optimized, as it likely is.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class (it's better in C++), and in your main class, a vector of this class, like that:

```
class Resolution {
public:
      Resolution(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::string const &);
      ~Resolution();

private:
      unsigned int Width;
      unsigned int Height;
      unsigned int Scale;
      std::string  Name;
};
```

And in your main class:

```
class MainClass {
public:
      ...
private:
      ...
      std::vector<Resolution *> m_res;
};
```

And in the cpp file:

```
MainClass::MainClass() {
           this->m_res.push_back(new Resolution(640, 360, 1, SD));
           this->m_res.push_back(new Resolution(1080, 720, 2, HD));
           this->m_res.push_back(new Resolution(1920, 1080, 3, FHD));
}
```

You can access to an element like that (Sure, you need the getter):

```
this->m_res[index].getValue();
```